# pg_restore connection to database failed error while restoring backup

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgresql-9.5, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a backup file in `tar` format and there is no problem while getting this backup. However, when trying to restore this backup using the following script, I encountered *"pg_restore: error: connection to database "db-dev" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "db-dev-user""* error after entering password.

```
pg_restore -v -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -d db-dev -U db-dev-user < C:\dB\db-dev.tar
```

I am trying to restore this backup to a Docker container where I can easily create an empty database with the same name (db-dev). I am also using Windows 10. So, how can I fix the problem? May the problem related to Docker?

Comment: No, that is a PostgreSQL problem. Look at the PostgreSQL log to make sure that it is really a password error. Then use the correct password.

Comment: Yes, but the error message sometimes may be generic. At first step, I want to be sure that if there is a password problem or not. For this reason, could you pls reply the following question? >>>

Comment: Should I use one of the user in the server where I restore database? Or the user or the backup database?

Comment: In the `pg_restore` command, I use `db-dev-user` that is a user of the database that backed up. However, should it be the user of the server where backup is restored?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, you must specify a user from the destination database with the  `-U` option of `pg_restore`, and you need to enter the password of that user.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake by entering the user from source (backed up) db. So, is it possible to create that user while creating empty database before restore? Or is it possible to create it while executing `pg_restore`?

Comment: You could use the `createuser` executable, but you need an existing user with high permissions (`postgres`?) to be able to create a new user.

Answer (score 0):

The `-U` option must specify an existing user in the target database, and you have to specify the user's password when calling `pg_restore`.

Use a user with the permissions required to create the dumped objects and make sure that the target's `pg_hba.conf` allows the user database access from your client machine.